# plotting surfaces with plotly

Tags: pytorch, plotly

I'm trying to rewrite this plot as an interactive plotly plot

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.scatter(X[:,0], X[:,1], Y)

with torch.no_grad():
  line = np.linspace(-3, 3, 50)
  xx, yy = np.meshgrid(line, line)
  Xgrid = np.vstack((xx.flatten(), yy.flatten())).T
  Xgrid_torch = torch.from_numpy(Xgrid.astype(np.float32))
  Yhat = model(Xgrid_torch).numpy().flatten()
  ax.plot_trisurf(Xgrid[:,0], Xgrid[:,1], Yhat, linewidth=0.2, antialiased=True)
  plt.show()
```

Comment: This is not reproducible and it's going to be difficult for people on SO to run your code without having at least a sample of your arrays `X` and `Y`. Also what error are you getting?

Comment: Hey Derek, how can I contact you to be able to show you the whole thing

Comment: I don't think you need to be able to show me the whole thing, just the minimum the what's needed to reproduce your plot. currently it looks like you have a mixture of matplotlib and plotly which isn't going to work. what did your code look like when it was in matplotlib? also what are the shape of `X` and `Y`? I don't even need any actual data – I can fill them with random numbers as long as I can get it running

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.